# AngularJS $timeout service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to have something visible for 3-4 seconds. I am trying to use $timeout for achieving that. Here's what I got so far:

```
$timeout(function() {
  debugger;
  $scope.$on(broadcastService.topErrorBar.show,
  function(event, message) {
    $scope.rootElement.addClass('is-visible');
    $scope.isVisible = true;
    $scope.message = message;
  });
}, 3000);

$timeout.cancel(function() {
    $scope.close();
});

$scope.close = function() {
  $scope.rootElement.removeClass('is-visible');
  $scope.isVisible = false;
};
```

This is not working and I'm not able to resolve the issue. What am I doing wrong? Should I use a timeout in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this :

```
$scope.$on(broadcastService.topErrorBar.show,
  function(event, message) {
    $scope.rootElement.addClass('is-visible');
    $scope.isVisible = true;
    $scope.message = message;
    $timeout(function() {
    $scope.close();
}, 3000);

$scope.close = function() {
  $scope.rootElement.removeClass('is-visible');
  $scope.isVisible = false;
};
```

On Broadcast , make element visible , start a timeout so that after 3 seconds $scope.close will be called. No need for $timeout.cancel in your case.

Answer (score 2):

what about:

```
$scope.$on(broadcastService.topErrorBar.show,
      function(event, message) {
          $scope.isVisible=false; 
           $timeout(function () { $scope.isVisible= true; }, 3000); 
      });
```

you have to use in html  `ng-show="isVisible">`

Comment: Best solution imo.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is inverted.  The function in a timeout fires **after** the time has elapsed.  You want the element to be visible, and then set visibility to false in your timeout function.  Here's an example.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.visible = true;
    $timeout(function () {
      $scope.visible = false;
      }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  This is always visible.
  <span ng-show="visible">This should hide after 3 seconds</span>
</div>
```